# Change value in JSON array and return updated array JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, function

I've got a JSON object where I get a product price (number) as a value.

*What I want is to convert the price values into strings in the existing object*

I use **map** function:

```
var prods = [
  {
    "id": "id-1",
    "price": 239000,
    "info": "info-1"
  },

  {
    "id": "id-2",
    "price": 90770,
    "info": "info-2"
  },

  {
    "id": "id-3",
    "price": 200787868,
    "info": "info-3"
  },
];


prods.map(function(a) {
         a.price.toString()
        .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(\D|$))/g, '$1 ');
})
```

I expect the **map** function to update my **prods** object, but it stays the same.

[(Un)working JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/zorewaf/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

I wonder, how to update the initial object to the one I need?

Comment: map returns a new array, so you have to do something like 
newarr = prods.map(function(a) { return
         a.price.toString()
        .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(\D|$))/g, '$1 ');
});

Comment: note the "return" is necessary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strings are immutable.

[`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) returns a new string and therefore you need an assignment.

And while you only need to change one property, you could use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
var prods = [{ id: "id-1", price: 239000, info: "info-1" }, { id: "id-2", price: 90770, info: "info-2" }, { id: "id-3", price: 200787868, info: "info-3" }];

prods.forEach(function(a) {
    a.price = a.price.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(\D|$))/g, '$1 ');
});

console.log(prods);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign value back to 'price' after replace

```
prods.map(function(a) {
         a.price = a.price.toString()
        .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(\D|$))/g, '$1 ');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use this one

**Sample Code**

```
prods.map(function(a) {
             a.price = ""+a.price;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that `map` apply a function to each element on array, you could return new array, it won't modify existing array, so you need assign new array to some variable.

```js
var prods = [
  {
 "id": "id-1",
 "price": 239000,
 "info": "info-1"
  },
  
  {
 "id": "id-2",
 "price": 90770,
 "info": "info-2"
  },
  
  {
 "id": "id-3",
 "price": 200787868,
 "info": "info-3"
  },
];


prods = prods.map(function(a) {
  a.price = a.price.toString()
   .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(\D|$))/g, '$1 ');
  return a;
});
console.log(prods);
```

Answer (score 0):

You only update the price inside the lambda passed to the map function.
You should create a new array where you store the new values.

```
let newArray= [];
prods.map(function(a) {
     a.price = a.price.toString()
    .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(\D|$))/g, '$1 ');
     newArray.push(a);
})
```

This would do the trick and lets your original array untouched.

[Try it out here in the Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?var%20prods%20%3D%20[%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22id-1%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22price%22%3A%20239000%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22info%22%3A%20%22info-1%22%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22id-2%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22price%22%3A%2090770%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22info%22%3A%20%22info-2%22%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22id-3%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22price%22%3A%20200787868%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22info%22%3A%20%22info-3%22%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A]%3B%0A%0A%0Alet%20newArray%3D%20[]%3B%0Aprods.map%28function%28a%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a.price%20%3D%20a.price.toString%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.replace%28%2F%28%5Cd%29%28%3F%3D%28%5Cd%7B3%7D%29%2B%28%5CD|%24%29%29%2Fg%2C%20%27%241%20%27%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20newArray.push%28a%29%3B%0A%7D%29%0A%0AnewArray%3B%0A)

Regards,
Felix